# XHTML doesn't support attribute placeholder

Tags: xhtml, placeholder

I am working on a simple website in XHTML. In the middle of the website there is the tag "input" with attribute "placeholder":  Then I check everything with trusty [XHTML Checker](https://validator.w3.org/check), but it sends me an error, that attribute "placeholder" is deprecated. What can I use instead to get the wanted result?

PS: I want to use XHTML because of its strictness.

Comment: You have to use [the XHTML syntax of HTML5](https://w3c.github.io/html/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml)

Comment: @User123 Can you explain why you need XHTML 1? If you tell us what you need exactly, I'm sure we can reach a solution. XHTML is very flexible.

Comment: In case, I can write in other XHTML's (1.1 and others). Thank you for all the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have noticed that the `placeholder` attribute performs as expected in XHTML 1.1 documents, even if it doesn't validate.
So no solution is necessary in order to make it work in the browsers, all we need to do is make it validate.

The go-to solution is to turn the document into XHTML5, but if that is not feasible for any reason (and I can think of one), what you need to do is append the definition for this attribute to the DTD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
  [
    <!ATTLIST input placeholder CDATA #IMPLIED>
  ]
>
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Input with placeholder in XHTML 1.1</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="#">
   <p><input placeholder="type&nbsp;here"/></p>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

That is all, a working and validating XHTML 1.1 file. Hope this helps!